# C++ Boost.asio Ping

Tags: c++, networking, boost, boost-asio, ping

I'm trying to make a program that will list all of the IP addresses of devices on a network.
One of the main components of this is being able to ping devices.
This program must work on Linux, Windows and Mac, so I chose the Boost library.

I managed to find this example in the documentation:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/icmp/ping.cpp

I am fairly experienced at C++ when using OpenGL 3.1 and Shaders but when I run this program it pings over and over (454+) and understanding it is throwing me for a loop (No pun intended) , it seems to contain a substantial amount of shorthand, functions I've never seen etc.

Is there a simpler method to ping a machine with Boost:asio?
or Is there a way I can get this method to run just 4 times and return the average response time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the linked example you have to change the `handle_receive` function to include a counter. When it has been called four times you tell the `io_server` object to stop (for this you either has to make it global, or store a reference to it in the `pinger` class) and not call `start_receive`.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Do you know what part in the program is requesting another response? I don't want to kill the service if and let the other machine keep responding.

Comment: @CoderWalker The part sending the "ping"? In the linked example that's `start_send` and `handle_timeout`.